# Tiled Map Service (TMS) in QGIS not showing highest resolution?

Tags: qgis, gdal, tile-map-service

I've added a [Tiled Map Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service) (TMS) in QGIS, but when i try and look at the highest zoom levels, the highest resolution I can see is level 19. When I add the service as a WMS, I can get the full resolution, level 21, but I can no longer call a specific image date from the server.

Does any one know how to call a higher resolution using a TMS in QGIS?

Is this a minidriver issue?

I don't have any code to post, but I've been fighting with this for days and have just run out of ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: By TMS do you mean the [Tile Map Scale](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/tms/) plugin, or something else?

Comment: [Tiled Map Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service). Its similar to [WMS or WTMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Tile_Service), except that it seems a bit easier to implement. The levels I'm referring to are the zoom levels.

Comment: If any one can clear the "unclear" tag, I figured out the solution to this and can post an answer.

Comment: I've re-opened this so that you can post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wasn't able to figure out a direct way to directly control the tiles resolution via adding a TMS service in qGIS, I was able to figure out this work around.
I installed the TileLayer plugin, which allows you to render TMS layers in [Slippy map format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map). I then wrote a .tsv in a text editor in the form:

```
 serviceName    https://serverlocation.com/maps?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}&nml=Vert.png&nmd=20160728&username={username}&password={password} 1   13  21  -117.0461   36.7615  -118.7123  36.9265
```

And pulled the service in using the plug in. The values after the username and password in the html string are the important bits. Not sure what "1" does, but 13 is the max resolution out, and 21 is the max resolution in. The 4 coordinate values are a bounding box.