# Display .mbtiles in QGIS for web use

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

I am attempting to display Open Map Tiles (https://openmaptiles.org/downloads/#country) into my QGIS project but I am getting nowhere when attempting to load them into my project. Is there a specific way to load the vector tiles into the project after I have downloaded them?

The purpose of this project is to make an offline web application that utilizes GeoJSON data, as well as the Vector Tiles.

Comment: I've had to deal with this previously. I asked about it here:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230640/tiled-map-service-tms-in-qgis-not-showing-highest-resolution . I don't have a ton of time right now to put into this question, but if my previous answer doesn't get you close hit me back and I can look into it.

Comment: I am unsure what I would name the service url since I downloaded the tiles to my local machine. I did come across this on Git https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin (Expected Release June 2017)

Comment: Hmm.. So I pulled down Belize from that site and nothing loaded. I use MB tiles all the time, but havent had this issue previously. I think their is an issue with the mbtiles rather than w. qgis

Comment: Do you have another solution for generating your own tiles? I assume TileMill or can you do it within QGIS?

Comment: Yes, typically I've been trying to go in the other direction where I have a streaming service and I'm trying to capture something a given level of zoom. Try the QuickMapServices plugin if you have internet access. If that works we might be able to do a work around.

Comment: So I installed the Vector Tile Reader plug in, and loaded a local file (belize); everything seems to be working fine for me. It did fail the first time I tried to load the tiles (QGIS often crashes or fails for me on a first attempt), but I tried again and its working fine.

Comment: I will download the U.S Tiles again and see if anything changes. I created a simple tile of the country without any details and was successful in displaying it in qgis, so it may be something with the Open Map Tile data.

Comment: I was able to create my own tiles following this blog post.http://blog.davidelner.com/create-map-with-tilemill-and-leaflet/                I wanted to know what approach would I need to do to generate these on my machine locally without a web server.